# The button command in my code isn't working

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I am writing a simple code in PyCharm as below but it doesn't seem to work:

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
window=tkinter.Tk()
Print=tkinter.Label(window,text="hey",fg="green",border=1)
Print.pack()
def man():
  Label2=tkinter.Label(text="hi")
  Label2.pack()
Button=tkinter.button
```

---

Comment: Python is case-sensitive, all the keywords should be lowercase.

Comment: You need to call the `button` function: `tkinter.button()`

Comment: When you run your posted code, PyCharm should show you where the errors are.

Comment: button = tkinter.Button()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code, completely fixed.

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
Print = Label(window,text="hey",fg="green",border=1)
Print.pack()
def man():
  Label2 = Label(text="hi")
  Label2.pack()
Button = Button(window, text = "Button", command = man)
Button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps!